# Javascript plain text charecter encoding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, character-encoding

I am working on a Javascript project that uses AngularJS. When I get data with http request, all characters are appearing well. For example, a downloaded string with ajax is **"räksmörgås"**, when written to the console as plain text, is appearing with ugly charecters.

`console.log("räksmörgås")` results into this: `r�ksm�rg�s`

Is this a file type encoding problem? Or are JavaScript strings always UTF-16 causing this problem?

Comment: Which charset you are declaring in content type in header?

Comment: index.html page <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not using the correct charset. For Swedish try to change the character encoding to `iso-8859-1` or `windows-1252`. I suppose that you are sending the server response without the correct headers and the browser interprets it as UTF-8 as the default charset.

So maybe changing the header charset as below will resolv the issue:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252 // or
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Another solution would be to declare your script tag with charset, this way forcing Js to handle the characters to be interpreted with a specific encoding.

```
<script src="yourscritp.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: I opened my javascript file with notepad++ and see encoding is ANSI. Is this a problem?

Comment: I think so... You may declare the <script> tag with  `charset`  parameter